# Find shortest path between 2 points, dynamic programming

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path

Here is my problem (path Graph)

I would like to find shothest path from A to F, i read that i should use Dijkstra algorithm, and i tried to do this but i have problems with setting edges:

in 79 line i set edges http://pastebin.com/UAZiP7qb

It is good option to solve this case by this algorithm? What should i do?

I can't set  edges correct:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // mark all the vertices
        Vertex A = new Vertex("A");
        Vertex B = new Vertex("B");
        Vertex C = new Vertex("C");
        Vertex D = new Vertex("D");
        Vertex E = new Vertex("E");
        Vertex F = new Vertex("F");


        // set the edges and weight
        A.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(B, 0) };
        B.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(E, 2) };
        E.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(F, 2) };
}
```

Comment: Please, include the source code in the question itself, instead of linking to some obnoxious ad filled sites. Also, specify what exactly is your problem, "have problems" is not descriptive enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You leave some adjancency lists as null. Check, before trying to iterate over them.

```
while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
    Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();
```

Next two lines added

```
    if (u.adjacencies == null)
        continue;

        // Visit each edge exiting u
        for (Edge e : u.adjacencies)
```

Comment: if i add this line how should i set the edges in main?

Comment: Just the way you set it now and don't forget to add both directions.

Comment: but if i add A.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C, 0) }; it replace me previous line ( A.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(B, 0) }; )
How should i set it?

Comment: You need to learn some Java basics, it seems. `B.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(A, 0), new Edge(E, 2), new Edge(D, 7) };`